# iTunesArtwork png files needed in xCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, itunesartwork, xcasset

In xCode 5 we have the ability to use the xcassets file to catalogue our app images. It appears that there is not a place for iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork2x files. Does this mean that these files are no longer needed in xCode 5? If they are needed, should we list them in the plist file? I had removed the icons list in the plist file and was hoping not to have to add it back again.

Comment: isn't iTunesArtWork used for the app store and used when you create the App record in iTunes Connect ? So, it should not be part of the package, right ?

Comment: I have always included it in the bundle. I thought we were supposed to. At the very least, for Ad Hoc purposes. Right?

Comment: I don't think the AdHoc iTunesArtwork setup has changed (still need the image). Except for that, it's been years since you've needed to include that file for an AppStore build. Just upload it to iTC.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Some time ago you were supposed to include your icon in large format 512x512 and 1024x1024 in your bundle when submitting an app to the AppStore, But after some changes in Xcode and iTunesConnect this is no longer necessary, you upload these two files directly to iTunes Connect and are not required in your bundle anymore.

Comment: What about for enterprise distribution

Comment: Sorry for the late response. For enterprise this 2 files are not needed since those images are for use only in the AppStore.

Answer (score 11):

The iTunesArtwork file is still used in AdHoc (and enterprise) distribution according to the official Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html

It is (as Ponchotg says) not necessary for appstore builds.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

Your xcode Project > Resources > App Icons

```
Rename following images
1. iTunesArtwork.png to iTunesArtwork 
2. iTunesArtwork@2x.png to iTunesArtwork@2x
```